# Using awk to grab Latest Timsstamp from file in Bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I have looked long and found out that you can't direct syslog output to both buffer and file via syslog-startup.conf in /etc. Please see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449156/how-to-set-up-syslog-to-log-to-both-file-buffer

My solution was to have a cron job running a bash script that will run every couple of minutes to grab the logs from the buffer and save it to a file onto my embedded linux device. The approach is I grab the first set of logs from buffer by doing something like `logread >> my_log_file` and afterwards I'm grabbing the last entry from my_log_file, get the timestamp from it, and then use it to grab new logs that have timestamp greater than this timestamp.

I'm running into an issue trying to plug in the timstamp into the awk command

```
if [ -f "${VAR_FILE}" ]; then
    LASTTS=$(tail -n 1 "${VAR_FILE}" | grep -o '^.*swi-')
    LASTTS=$(sed 's/.\{5\}$//' <<< "$LASTTS")
    echo $LASTTS
fi

awk '$0 > "${LASTTS}"' msgs >> "${VAR_FILE}"
```

I keep getting all logs not the ones > my last timestamp. It works if I change the awk command to have an actual date hardcoded as such

`awk '$0 > "Mar 15 14:20:50"' msgs >> "${VAR_FILE}"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you need to log to the buffer rather than direct to the file?

Comment: @jhnc I need to have logs coming thought both buffer and file. The file is going to be saved on SD card which is prone to corruption and such so in case that happens we want to have logs in buffer we can access

Comment: Might be more reliable to use the network option to send to a central loghost. What is an example of your logfile contents?

Comment: Be aware that your date format is not sortable.

Answer (score 1):

There are three cases:

1. nothing yet saved to file
2. buffer has new content and some old content
3. buffer only has new content (we missed something)

We want to append only the new content from buffer.

Assuming the busybox awk and shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -f "$log" ]; then
    # case 1
    logread > "$log"
else
    prev="$(tail -n 1 "$log")"

    # case 2 or 3
    logread | awk -v prev="$prev" '
        new { print; next }
        $0==prev { new=1 }
        END { exit !new } # "fail" if no old line
    ' >> "$log" 

    # case 3
    [ -n $? ] && logread >> "$log"
fi
```

Comment: I don't actually know what output logread produces. If the timestamp is insufficiently granular, it would be possible with this code to duplicate lines. eg. seen: `... / t1a / t1b / t1c / t1a`, buffer: `t1a / t1b / t1c / t1a / t2d` should append `t2d` but will actually append `t1b / t1c / t1a / t2d`. However, nothing should be lost unless the checks are done so far apart that we hit case 3.

Answer (score 0):

SO the answer I was looking for is:

```
awk -v var="$LASTTS" '$0 > var' msgs >> "${VAR_FILE}"
```

This tends to solve the issue I was having. But now I'm faced with the fact that it duplicates always the last timestamp is re-copied

Comment: I think this may fail when your last line is `Mar ...` and the buffer contains `Apr ...`